# how to debug bookmark anchors not working

Tags: html, anchor

I've got a really complicated html page and I've added some bookmark anchors at various points.  The anchors look like this:

```
<a href="#foo bar">click here for foo bar</a>
lorum ipsum etc
<a name="foo bar">foo bar</a>
```

But when you click on them, nothing happens - the url in the address bar doesn't change, and the page doesn't move.

If I take my anchors out and put them into a simpler page, they start working, so I think something must be interfering with the navigation somehow, but I can't think how to nail it down.  I wondered about an error in the javascript somewhere that was cancelling the navigation, but the page has thousands of lines of javascript and I've not found anything suspicious yet.

The problem occurs in both Chrome and Firefox.

How can I debug this problem?

---

<del>UPDATE: Could this be a CSS issue?  the target anchors are within a `<div>` with the CSS property `overflow:auto;`.  This is causing the scroll bar to appear inside the div instead of the edge of the page - which was not the case with my simple text page.</del>

UPDATE 2: overflow:auto doesn't break named anchors; [tested with a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/rDaYL/)

Comment: Are spaces allowed in bookmarks ?

Comment: I'd start by looking for JavaScript that's stopping the click event from propagating or prevent the default action. If you're using jQuery, http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ and http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @sjums I tried copying the bookmarks to a simple test page, and they worked OK with spaces.  I'll experiment anyway though - anything is worth trying at this point.

Comment: @j08691 And in most cases simply `return false;` somewhere in an event handler. I suspect that too. Try disabling Javascript first and see if they work.

Comment: @bazmegakapa unfortunately the whole section of the page is loaded via ajax so not easy to test without javascript - and pulling the offending section out into a simple test page didn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you got an `<a>` within another `<a>`? Or within a noscript or other "odd" tag?

Comment: @Ben I can't see any nested `<a>`s.  Also, cutting and pasting the offending section would leave them intact, but that doesn't reproduce the problem :(  There are no `<noscript>` tags in the page.

Comment: @j08691 I've tried grepping and reading though the code, I can't find any references to stopPropagation() or preventDefault() in the js - there are some in jQuery itself but I'm assuming that wouldn't cause me problems.  I've also looked for event handlers that `return false;` - I can't see any that would seem to apply to an anchor being clicked.

Comment: When you said "there are some in jQuery itself but I'm assuming that wouldn't cause me problems." what do you mean?

Comment: @j08691 I used firebug to search for references to preventDefault() and stopPropagation() on my page. Firebug searches all the .js files included with the page, including jquery, jquery ui, jquery plugins and drupal libraries.  preventDefault() did not appear in my own code, but it did appear in jQuery itself; frankly I don't understand most of the jQuery library so I'm going to leave it well alone for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was definitely a scripting problem rather than the syntax of the anchor.  I eventually (accidently) debugged the problem by adding some invalid javascript to the click() handler, which broke the click handler but caused the anchors to start working again.  I was able to proceed from there.

Comment: But from the question that you asked, I'm not sure that this would be considered the 'accepted answer'. After doing a quick test, it looks like using the id attribute (the first answer) should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

named anchors need to have a have a one word name or id (id better, since name is being depecated)

this will work:

```
<a href="#foo-bar">click here for foo bar</a>
    lorum ipsum etc
<a id="foo-bar">foo bar</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I'll change my code to use id for future compatability, although it seems that for now multi-word anchors do actually work - check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wFcnk/

Comment: yep, I tried it out after answering and it does appear to work (odd!), but according to w3c, only strings matching the pattern [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9:_.-]* should be used for ids. eg:"and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters." from here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#foo bar">click here for foo bar</a>
lorum ipsum etc
<a id="foo bar">foo bar</a>
```

So basically change your name attribute for an id one.

Also... I think that it will basically be looking for "foo" rather than "foo bar". I haven't tested this though.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  it turned out my anchors were actually working ok, it was just some duff javascript causing my problem.  By the way, I did a quick test of the anchors; you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wFcnk/

Answer (score 0):

One little quirk... Don't have any HTML tags between your anchor tags or the bookmark won't work !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31106539)

Comment: This is completely incorrect